# Scala plugin and Rational Developer for System z with Java not working

Tags: eclipse, scala, compatibility, scala-ide

Hi all you clever people.

I'm a Scala enthusiast which fully believe in Scala as a tool which will raise productivity, compared to Java in many areas. I have been a happy user of the eclipse scala plugin for some time. However now the time has come for me to introduce it for my colleagues, and to my big disappointment the Scala plugin doesn't seem to work with Rational Developer for System z with Java.

This is a big issue for me, since I wouldn't like to force my colleagues to have another eclipse installation just for the Scala plugin, and when building.
The problems I get seems to be related to the java launcher, and also the aspectj weaving. 
Is there somebody there know if this is a known issue, or what I else should do.

If nobody knows about this issue, I guess the next place to go, is to place a bug description on the Scala plugin, however I don't know the fix time for these kind of issues.

Many thanks in advance.
Regards Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably right in your analysis that it's something to do with the aspectj weaving. Does the Rational plugin use aspects at all? If so, that may be the problem. In the past there have been a number of problems due to the scala-ide use of aspects. There has been a lot of work done, and the latest versions (as of 15.03.2012) are a lot better.

Two things to try:

1. Try the latest version of the scala-ide plugin.
2. If the above doesn't work, raise a bug (http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets) but mention specifically that you're using Rational developer, and if you can identify the rational plugin that's using aspects, even better. Please attach a url which points to the version of the rational plugin that you're using.

Comment: You mean I should try out the nightly build? I will do that then. I will come back with the result.

Comment: I have added a ticket on it now - http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000934